# Shiny App: How to subset the output results depends on the input variable

Tags: r, select, input, shiny, output

I just take my first step in the Shiny app. And I have already blocked. I have a data frame and I want to present variety of analysis of this data. Among others, I would like to show the maximum value of one type of pollen for each year. So I would like to see when there was a maximum value (date and day of the year) and see the maximum value of pollen.

The data looks like this:
Date Year Day_Year Total Grass Betula
1 1998-01-01 1998        1     0     0      0
2 1998-01-02 1998        2     0     0      0
3 1998-01-03 1998        3     0     0      0
4 1998-01-04 1998        4     0     0      0
5 1998-01-05 1998        5     0     0      0
6 1998-01-06 1998        6     0     0      0

```
'data.frame':   8766 obs. of  6 variables:
```

$ Date    : Date, format: "1998-01-01" "1998-01-02" ...
$ Year    : num  1998 1998 1998 1998 1998 ...
$ Day_Year: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Total   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Grass   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Betula  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

My results look like this:

Type of Pollen: Total Pollen

Date Year Day_Year Total Grass Betula
239  1998-08-27 1998      239   260   260      0
596  1999-08-19 1999      231   219   215      0
945  2000-08-02 2000      215   179   173      0
1250 2001-06-03 2001      154   116     0    113

My problem:
When I choose Total Pollen I don't want to see the columns: Grass and Betula. I would like to see only the columns: Year, Date, Day_Year, Total.

I would be grateful for the help :)

```
# Function

max_all <- function(x) if(length(x))x==max(x)
```

## ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput("variable","Type of Pollen:",c("Total Pollen","Birch Pollen","Grass Pollen")),verbatimTextOutput("max"))
```

## server

```
server <- function(input, output) {datasetInput <- reactive({switch(input$variable,"Total Pollen" = Ak_sub$Total,"Birch Pollen" = Ak_sub$Betula,"Grass Pollen" = Ak_sub$Grass)})output$max <- renderPrint({ variable <- datasetInput()max <-subset(Ak_sub,!!ave(variable, Year,FUN=max_all))return(max)})}
```

## Create Shiny app

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: This is the screenshot. The results are almost what I would like. But when I choose the type of pollen: Birch Pollen, I would like to display the results for Betula. I do not want to see the columns: Total and Grass.]

Answer (score 0):

This will sum up the counts of all pollens (e.g. grass or betula) for each day:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~Date, ~Year, ~Day_Year, ~Grass, ~Betula,
  "1998-01-01", 1998, 1, 10, 3,
  "1998-01-02", 1998, 2, 0, 2
)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date, Year, Day_Year)) %>%
  group_by(Date, Year, Day_Year) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(value))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Date', 'Year'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#> # Groups:   Date, Year [2]
#>   Date        Year Day_Year Total
#>   <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1998-01-01  1998        1    13
#> 2 1998-01-02  1998        2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @danloo, thank you for your immediate answer, but it is not exactly what I need. I attached the screenshot to my post. The results are almost what I would like. But when I choose the type of pollen: Birch Pollen, I would like to display the results for Betula. I do not want to see the columns: Total and Grass. How to do that?